# Preg_replace doesn't work when the string contains numbers

Tags: php, regex, string, integer, preg-replace

So i have a string with flags like this: <<-- name -->> and now I want to replace all of them for ''.

I made the following function:

```
function removeFlags($output) {
    $output = preg_replace('/\<<--[^-->>]+-->>/', '', $output);
    return $output;
}
```

It works fine for the most flags but not when they contain numbers.
For example: <<-- Model -->> will just be replaced for '', but <<-- 360 -->> will not be removed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you, as you want to replace anything that is preceded and succeeded by a certain pattern

`$output = preg_replace('/\<<--.+?-->>/', '', $output);`

And I think your pattern should have worked for numbers as well, but do the numbers have a space before and after them?

Comment: Thanks. It does indeed.

Comment: It has a space before it or a _

Answer (score 1):

This pattern works:

> `$output = preg_replace('/\<<--[^.]+-->>/', '', $output);`

Answer (score 1):

The hyphen `-`  inside a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) indicates a range. You are accidentally [negating](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) a range from `-` to `>` which contains digits `0-9` so it can not match `<<-- 360 -->>`

[image]

To match a hyphen literally, put it at start or end of the class or escape it with a backslash.
Also you need to add only one of the different characters to the character class.

```
<<--[^>-]+-->>
```

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aM8qA2/1)

Comment: @LarsVelthuis That's no reason why I should not point out the problem : )

Comment: Thanks. It gives me a better understanding of how preg_replace works.

Comment: @LarsVelthuis I find this answer very helpful and as bobble bubble writes it points out the root of the problem why the pattern did not work.